# How to use cordova-plugin-android-permissions in Ionic 3 for access default sms application android?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3

I have created a simple application that only functions to send a message but the function uses the SMS application from the cellphone and not from the application that I made, my application runs fine, but there is a problem with the SMS permissions that make the function blocked or unable to run, can you help?